# Convert a scale factor into a note transposition value

Tags: math, audio, audio-player

I need to convert a scale factor, such as `0.5` or `2.0`, into a note transposition value. Here are some examples:

`0.5` - Half of the original pitch, so the function should return `-12` (Down one octave).

`1.0` - Pitch is unchanged, so the function should return `0`.

`2.0` - Double the original pitch, so the function should return `12` (Up one octave).

`4.0` - Quadruple the original pitch, so the function should return `24` (Up two octaves).

It doesn't matter what programming language you use since this is more of a math question, but I am currently using Javascript. The input number is floating-point and the output should be an integer rounded to the nearest whole number (since you can't have a partial note).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already solved this, actually. The key was to handle three cases, one where scaleFactor === 1, another when scaleFactor < 1, and the last when scaleFactor > 1.

```js
const noteFactor = (scaleFactor) => {
  if (scaleFactor === 1) return 0
  if (scaleFactor < 1) {
    return Math.round(-1 * ((1 / scaleFactor) * 6))
  } else {
    return Math.round(scaleFactor * 6)
  }
}
```